# What is the reason for assigning this to a locale variable without a callback?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

As far as I know assigning `this` to a variable is used within callbacks where the `this` scope may change. But digging through the ExtJS source I found it used in all sorts of functions but not always. So is there any reason that I would assign `this` to a local variable beneath the scope or is the ExtJS source just struggling with different developer styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this, the most significant being that using a local variable will save a few bytes during compression of the files.  It may not seem like much for a small bit of code, but it can add up a good bit over time.

There is a long thread at the Sencha forums talking about this very issue: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132045.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me to the right direction so accepted and +1. Anyway I felt to write a more complex answer and added this to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

@kevhender pointed me to the right [sencha forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132045) where evan has given a very good explanation.

It's only for the size. And here's a example:

```
function doA() {
    var me = this;

    me.a();
    me.b();
    me.c();
    me.d();
    me.e();
    me.f();
    me.g();
    me.h();
    me.i();
    me.j();
    me.k();
    me.l();
}

function doB() {
    this.a();
    this.b();
    this.c();
    this.d();
    this.e();
    this.f();
    this.g();
    this.h();
    this.i();
    this.j();
    this.k();
    this.l();
}
```

Compressed we get:

```
function doA(){var a=this;a.a();a.b();a.c();a.d();a.e();a.f();a.g();a.h();a.i();a.j();a.k();a.l()}
function doB(){this.a();this.b();this.c();this.d();this.e();this.f();this.g();this.h();this.i();this.j();this.k();this.l()};
```

It adds up.

---

**According to that we should**

- **NOT** use a local var if we use this only up to three times

  ```
  function doA(){var a=this;a.a();a.b();a.c();};
  function doB(){this.a();this.b();this.c();};
  ```
- and use it if we use this more often then three times

  ```
  function doA(){var a=this;a.a();a.b();a.c();a.d()};
  function doB(){this.a();this.b();this.c();this.d()};
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly stated `this` is sometimes used in places where the scope might change.

There are cases where you want to do the same to make sure there are no scoping issues.

Other than that, the devs sometimes just assign `this` to a variable out of habit more than out of necessity.